# $\int x^3$ $\sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Could someone explain to me how I can find $\int x^3$$\sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx$ ?

Comment: Do you mean "indefinite" instead of "undefined"?

Comment: Sorry, I adjusted.

Comment: Straightforward integration by parts:  $-\frac{1}{15} \left(1-x^2\right)^{3/2} \left(3 x^2+2\right)$.

Comment: Could you explain the steps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the power of $x$ outside the radical is odd, this is most easily accomplished with the substitution $u = 1-x^2$ rather than a trig substitution. Then $du = -2x\,dx$ and
\begin{multline}
\int x^3\sqrt{1-x^2}dx = -\frac{1}{2}\int(1-u)\sqrt{u}\,du = -\frac{1}{2}\int\left(u^{1/2}-u^{3/2}\right)\,du  = \frac{u^{5/2}}{5} - \frac{u^{3/2}}{3}\\ = \frac{(1-x^2)^{5/2}}{5}-\frac{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}{3} = -\frac{2+3x^2}{15}(1-x^2)^{3/2}
\end{multline}

Comment: (+1) modulo the constant of integration, this is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Using a u substition is very useful in this case

$$\int x^3\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$
$$u=1-x^2$$

$$du=-2x\hspace{1mm} dx$$

$$dx=-\frac{1}{2x} du$$

$$\int x^3\sqrt{u} \cdot -\frac{1}{2x}du$$
$$-\frac{1}{2} \int (1-u)\sqrt{u} \hspace{1mm}du$$ 
$$-\frac{1}{2} \int u^{\frac{1}{2}}-u^{\frac{3}{2}} \hspace{1mm}du$$ 
$$-\frac{1}{2}  (\frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{2}{5}u^{\frac{5}{2}})+C $$ 
$$\frac{1}{5}u^{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{1}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$$
$$\frac{1}{5}(1-x^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{1}{3}(1-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$$

Never forget the $+C$ when dealing with indefinite integrals

Comment: Please use an online utility to check your answer I like this one: https://www.integral-calculator.com/
Wolfram alpha also disagrees with you: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+1%2F5(1-x%5E2)%5E(5%2F2)-1%2F3(1-x%5E2)%5E(3%2F2)

Comment: Bruh I got the same answer as eyeballfrog

Comment: Sorry. I miscopied your answer into Mathematica and it is correct.

Comment: Never forget the +C when dealing with (indefinite) integrals

Answer (score 4):

To integrate $\displaystyle \int x^3 \sqrt{1 - x^2} dx$, I would most naturally use $u$-substitution with $u = 1 - x^2$ and $du = -2x\hspace{1mm}dx$. Then this is
$$\begin{align} \int x^3 \sqrt{1 - x^2} dx &= \frac{-1}{2}\int (-2x\hspace{1mm}dx) (x^2) \sqrt{1 - x^2} \\
&= \frac{-1}{2}\int (1 - u) \sqrt{u} \; du \\
&= \frac{-1}{2} \bigg( \frac{u^{3/2}}{3/2} - \frac{u^{5/2}}{5/2}\bigg) + C.
\end{align}$$
Substituting back in gives the answer
$$
\frac{(1-x^2)^{5/2}}{5} - \frac{(1 - x^2)^{3/2}}{3} + C.
$$